# Is it possible to target the spouse of someone who meets certain demographics/interests with a Facebook ad?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

Does Facebook have a way to target the spouse of someone who meets certain demographic/interest criteria? For example, could you target an ad to spouses of firefighters or spouses of teachers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no direct way. There are seven ways to [target an audience](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/433385333434831):

1. Custom Audiences
2. Location
3. Demographics
4. Age & Gender
5. Interests
6. Behaviors
7. Connections

In your case you can use [Custom Audiences](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/170456843145568) option. For this You should know all the firefighters' and teachers' spouse Facebook ID or email address or username.

You can try Demographics/Interests also but it will target all the people.

Comment: You say there are seven ways, but you list six. Is one missing or is that just an oversight?

Comment: Number seven is *Connections*. @serenesat just forgot to add the *7.* after Behaviours.

Comment: @fionaredmond: Yes, you are write. _@AIE_. Just added. I was forget to write _7._ before _Connections_.